# In PHP, does sleep(0) still yield or is it ignored?

Tags: php

In PHP, if you use `sleep(0);`, will it be ignored (either by PHP or by the OS), or will it still yield execution to another thread temporarily? Does it incur any overhead? Does it depend on the version of PHP or the OS?

Comment: It's a function call. I would be surprised if it's ignored.

Comment: @Andreas But if it simply returns immediately without actually doing anything, it's effectively ignored.

Comment: @Andreas I mean I realize it will incur a function call overhead because there's no way the interpreter has the information it needs to bail out of at least entering the function... but I meant does it have the massive overhead of putting the thread to sleep and causing context switches and waiting until the OS reschedules the thread. When I asked if it would be ignored, I meant would it still make the system call to yield execution.

Comment: @Barmar but I doubt they built that function with a `if 0 exit`. I for sure would assume if you call a function you want something done. Especially with a function like sleep. I can more understand if echo has a quick exit.

Comment: @philraj go look in the PHP code and see what sleep does.

Comment: @Andreas I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to look into this again since someone upvoted the question.

As seen in [basic_functions.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ef5558a8cda5a8c62e8de7694202ac669d74f1b3/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L1229), it calls a function named `php_sleep`:

```c
/* {{{ Delay for a given number of seconds */
PHP_FUNCTION(sleep)
{
    zend_long num;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_LONG(num)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    if (num < 0) {
        zend_argument_value_error(1, "must be greater than or equal to 0");
        RETURN_THROWS();
    }

    RETURN_LONG(php_sleep((unsigned int)num));  // <----- php_sleep
}
/* }}} */
```

`php_sleep` is defined in [php.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php.h#L283) as follows (unless PHP is running on win32):

```c
#ifndef PHP_WIN32
#define php_sleep sleep
extern char **environ;
#endif  /* ifndef PHP_WIN32 */
```

So it's using the standard `sleep` which is being included with `unistd.h` elsewhere in the file, whose implementation probably depends on which platform you're using and which flavor of libc and all that. I've seen posts on the internet claiming that old versions of the function would explicitly check if the argument was 0 and early exit, and others saying that `sleep(0)` is one way of cooperatively yielding your thread to the OS for the shortest time possible.

So after all this time, unsatisfyingly, the answer is: ***it depends.***